# Replacing a string with an image within flexslider.js

Tags: javascript, string, image, wordpress, flexslider

So I have been trying to use @font-face to try and style the directional arrows of [this website](http://dianabaumbach.danielalt.com) and haven't had any luck. All my other @font-face has been working but this one won't. So I need to add pink arrows to the page; so I could use an image instead. I think I found where the code is; however my Javascript knowledge is pretty slim. If I am posting the wrong code I am sorry, but here is it. What I need to do is find out how to replace the "(" with an image linking to the arrow images. Thanks in advance.

```
directionNav:!0,prevText:"(",nextText:")"
```

Comment: So basically, I would like prevText:"http://imagelink.com/image.png" instead of the string, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance, there aren't left/right disambiguators on the CSS selectors for those elements, which makes the straightforward jQuery code to put image elements a bit more complicated. You could still find the *list* of relevant DOM nodes and then assume that the first is left and the second is right, and append image children.

But more simply than that, as a first approximation to something acceptable, could you simply use the `&lsaquo;` (for angle-quotes) or `&larr;` (for actual arrows)? Perhaps that's where you started.

We can see from

```
jQuery(".flex-direction-nav").length;
```

that there is a single element with the CSS class surrounding your navigation, and similarly

```
jQuery(".flex-direction-nav li").length;
```

shows that there are just the two `li` elements, in the way that I was talking about above. So you could then swap the images manually with the following couple lines

```
jQuery(jQuery(".flex-direction-nav li a")[0]).text("").append("<img src='path/to/left.png' alt='left'>");
jQuery(jQuery(".flex-direction-nav li a")[1]).text("").append("<img src='path/to/right.png' alt='right'>");
```

which clears out the parentheses and appends a suitable image to the link tag contained within the `li` elements that are the children of the navigation container. It's possible that one of those `jQuery` wrappers isn't necessary, but it shouldn't hurt anything.

You should be able to put those lines wherever you have on-page-load initialization code happening. If you don't already *have* any initialization code, you can pass a function to `jQuery` directly:

```
jQuery(function() { console.log("This is called when the page is ready."); });
```

I'm not 100% I'm answering the question you're asking, but I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hey Matt, Thanks for helping, I see what you are talking about; however I am not sure where it goes. The following is the jquery code for the flex slider:
http://dianabaumbach.danielalt.com/wp-content/themes/canvas/includes/js/jquery.flexslider.min.js